# Ruby on the rails, devise and using user to limit existing model

Tags: ruby, devise

I am very new to Ruby (2-3 days) and am using it on an existing DB.  I have a user table (previously built in Joomla) and have managed to get it working (well, logging in and out), but i need to constrain another model i.e. 'Leads' to the user that is logged in.

I have been able to get ALL the current 'leads' output and using CRUD operations, but i would like to know how to limit the data based on the user that is logged in.

The 'leads' model was generated using scaffolding and the 'set_table_name' and 'set_primary_key' attributes have been overridden.  I have also added

`belongs_to :user,
   :class_name => "user",
   :foreign_key => "leadid"`

to the model.

The 'user' model is as follows

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and      :omniauthable
`establish_connection :web_development
 set_table_name "users"
 set_primary_key "id"

 has_many :leads,
       :class_name => "Lead",
       :foreign_key => "LeadID"

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

 # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
 attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

   alias :devise_valid_password? :valid_password?
   def valid_password?(password)
     return true (temp to bypass the password)
   end 
 end
```

Many thanks
Rudy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise provides an accessor to the currently logged in user with `current_user`. Since it looks like you have the relationship set up correctly, if you want to show only the leads for the logged in user in your index action of the controller you just need this:

```
def index
    @leads = current_user.leads
end
```

Comment: Will give it a try and report back, looks like it will work. Many thanks

Comment: I made the changes and i can see from the console output that it is querying the leads table.  However, unfortunately, my user field is 'joined' to my 'leads' table not by the 'id' primary key but by a 'userid' field.  i.e. User.UserID joins to Lead.UserID as opposed to User.ID joining to Lead.ID.  Had a look on the web but could not find how to override the field.  Thanks again

Comment: It sounds like you just need to update your belongs_to in the Lead model. So in Lead.rb, change the relationship to `belongs_to :user, :primary_key => "UserID"`

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it is still using the ID field value i.e. the Primary Key to do the join.  Any other ideas?  Thanks again

Comment: Hi, you were right, i had to update the User model to include the option :primary_key => "LeadID".  Thanks Rudy

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to your leads_controller

```
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

That should take care of ensuring that a user is properly authenticated before allowing access to any of the actions in that controller.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tip, that will be very useful